# Web API vs Self Hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Sorry If i confuse anyone with the question, I am trying hard to make the scenario clear.

Am writing Test Cases for a method that invoke HttpClient Methods.So, I ended up writing following Test Method.

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task CallComplexRefTypeParamAPI_Get_GetResponseWithParamatersNameValueAppended()
    {

        #region Arrange
        //var resourceURL = @"http://localhost:32662/api/user/ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse";
        var resourceURL = @"/api/user/ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse";
        var restHelper = new RestHelper(_BaseAddress);

        string ParameterKey1 = "VariableStr";
        string ParameterValueStr = "Jia";

        string ParameterKey2 = "VariableInt";
        int ParameterValueInt = 1;

        string ParameterKey3 = "VariableBool";
        bool ParameterValueBool = true;

        string ParameterKey4 = "VariableDateTime";
        DateTime ParameterValueDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        ComplexRefType ParameterComplexRefType = new ComplexRefType()
        {
            VariableBool = ParameterValueBool,
            VariableDateTime = ParameterValueDateTime,
            VariableInt = ParameterValueInt,
            VariableStr = ParameterValueStr
        };
        string result;
        #endregion

        #region Act
        using (WebApp.Start<WebApiStartup>(_BaseAddress))
        {
            restHelper.AddURLParameters("VariableComplexRef", ParameterComplexRefType);
            restHelper.AddURLParameters("DummyStr", "DummyStr");
            result = await restHelper.ExecuteAsync<string>(HttpMethod.Get, resourceURL);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        Assert.AreEqual<string>(string.Format("{0}={1}&{2}={3}&{4}={5}&{6}={7}",
                                    ParameterKey1, ParameterValueStr,
                                    ParameterKey2, ParameterValueInt,
                                    ParameterKey3, ParameterValueBool,
                                    ParameterKey4, ParameterValueDateTime), result);
        #endregion

    }
```

On other side, I have my Test Controller with following 2 methods.

```
       public string GetMultipleTypeParamStringResponse(string VariableStr, int VariableInt, DateTime VariableDateTime)
    {
        return string.Format("VariableStr={0}&VariableInt={1}&VariableDateTime={2}", VariableStr, VariableInt, VariableDateTime);
    }


    public string GetComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse([FromUri]ComplexRefType VariableComplexRef, string DummyStr)
    {
        return string.Format("VariableStr={0}&VariableInt={1}&VariableBool={2}&VariableDateTime={3}",
                                VariableComplexRef.VariableStr,
                                VariableComplexRef.VariableInt,
                                VariableComplexRef.VariableBool,
                                VariableComplexRef.VariableDateTime);
    }
```

I have the same Controller replicated in an Web API application. If run the test method, pointing to the Self-Hosted API, the application hits "GetMultipleTypeParamStringResponse" instead of "GetComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse". However, if I run it against the Web API, it hits the rightful "GetComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse" method.

Could someone please help me understand why this behavior ? On both cases, the Query String generated looks to be similar.

Self Hosted
http://localhost:8888/api/user/ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse?VariableStr=Jia&VariableInt=1&VariableBool=True&VariableDateTime=1%2F5%2F2017 3:49:10 PM&DummyStr=DummyStr

Web API
http://localhost:32662/api/user/ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse?VariableStr=Jia&VariableInt=1&VariableBool=True&VariableDateTime=1%2F5%2F2017 3:50:58 PM&DummyStr=DummyStr

Comment: Can you try adding explicit [Route("api/user/ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse")] attribute into your test controller methods.

Comment: Tried that, but that didn't quite help. It still behaves in the same way

Comment: can you also post the route configurations you have in your test api application?

Comment: '        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }'

Comment: can you try changing the routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" in the route configurations and include the Route attribute as a mentioned in the previous comment(also mark the method explicitly with [HttpGet]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. That was so stupid of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the routetemplate in your route configuration to

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Mark the methods with explicit Route attribute and HttpGet verb like below

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/user/ComplexReferenceTypeParamStringResponse")]
```